# How to make log4j&logback compatible after upgrading poi to v5?

Tags: apache-poi, log4j2, logback

I'm facing problems after upgrading the latest poi 5.2.2.
Now my project is using the springboot default logback to print the logs.
but after upgrading the poi

implementation "org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.2"

it must let me implement the log4j implementation. so I added

implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.2'

then this works in my local environment.

However got below errors in docker environment

```
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings  for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. 
Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory 
loaded from file:/opt//BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to 
prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory
at org.springframework.util.Assert.instanceCheckFailed(Assert.java:702)
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:621)
at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.get
```

below is my build.gradle file

```
configurations.all {
exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-entitymanager'
exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
exclude group: 'log4j'
exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging' }

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.springframework:spring-context-support"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation"
implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client"
implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose"
implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server"

implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11"  
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.2'
```

btw, basing POI official introduction, it also supports other logging framework, so I also tried this jar

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html

but I still get error like below

```
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: log4j-slf4j-impl cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.validateContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:60)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:44)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:53)
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:363)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:174)
... 1 more
```

this really drives me crazy, could you help me on this?

Comment: one of your dependencies is pulling in log4j-slf4j-impl - you will need to exclude it - you can not have log4j-slf4j-impl and log4j-to-slf4j on your classpath at the same time - you will get an endless loop of log4j converting to slf4j and then to log4j and then back again, ad infinitum

Comment: thanks, I resolved it. it's so wired, I can't find the log4j-slf4j-impl in my local env. but got this error in the docker env. so I forced to exclude it, then startup sucessfully.